# QTextEdit foreach

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I'm making a simple code text editor in Qt where it picks up C++ keywords and colors them. I know that Qt has a `foreach` function, but how can I use it live with the QTextEdit that the user is typing into?

Here is what I have tried, where if I type the word `Hi` into the `textEdit` then it pops up in the debug. This didn't work.

```
QLinkedList<QTextEdit* > list;
QString str = "Hi";
foreach(str, list)
    qDebug() << str;
```

I think I saw this idea somewhere on a forum, but again it didn't work. If you can help out, any suggestions are helpful! Thanks!

Edit:

Here's what I have now:

```
QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
QString str = "Hi";
foreach(str, text)
    qDebug() << str;
```

Except  `qDebug()` outputs `Hi` every time I print a character rather than when I print all of `Hi`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you have a list of `QTextEdit`s but to get your code to compile, you have to do like below.

```
QLinkedList<QTextEdit*> list;
QTextEdit* textEdit = NULL;
foreach(textEdit, list)
    qDebug() << textEdit->toPlainText();
```

The problem with your code is that you are trying to assign a `QTextEdti*` to a `QString`.

**Answer to the question asked in the comment:**

Connect `textChanged()` signal of `textEdit` to a slot.

`connect(textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), SLOT(onTextChanged()))`

In the slot, split the text in textEdit with space character and iterate.

```
private void MyWnd::onTextChanged()
{
    QStringList wordList = textEdit->toPlainText().split();
    foreach (QString word, wordList )
    {
        qDebug() << word;
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha my bad, I messed that up. What I really want to do is to make a list of `QStrings`. I can't figure out how to link that list with the text edit though.  So how can I make it so that if the user types in the word `Hi`, it prints `Hi` in `qDebug()`? In other words, how can I make thie `QLinkedList` look through the `textEdit` text?

Answer (score 0):

OMG you doing that completely wrong and asking for solution which doesn't help in your problem in fact it makes it even worse.

Also all you need is documented in Qt.
Check this [Qt example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html).

Comment: Okay will this answer doesnt help. I tried to put code so that people could see what i have tried. By telling me  that im doing it completely wrong and leaving it off there instead of showing what i could have done, this isnt any help

Comment: Are you kidding? Should I copy paste whole code from Qt example, which is completely described? Man just copy paste parts of code from link and everything will work out of the box. What you don't understand from link I gave you?